# Circular icons act as squares

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm creating a card in bootstrap with some social media icons (Font-awesome). For some reason all my icons are treated as boxes and have a black outline around them. My hover shadows also wrap around the square rather than the icon itself.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

[image]

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <a href="" type="button" class="btn-floating btn-small">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#00aced;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x" style="color:#ffffff;"></i>
    </span>
  </a>

  <a href="" type="button" class="btn-floating btn-small">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#0077B5;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x" style="color:#ffffff;"></i>
    </span>
  </a>

  <a href="" type="button" class="btn-floating btn-small">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#171515;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-github fa-stack-1x" style="color:#ffffff;"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should either use `text-shadow` or `filter: drop-shadow` instead of `box-shadow`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The icons still have that box around them even without a shadow though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The box border is being generated by they `type="button"` parameter in your anchors, which has a defined `-webkit-appearance: button;` in bootstrap's stylesheet.  So remove that `type="button"` parameter, or style it as desired.

As for the shadows, if you want them to keep the shape of the icon instead of being boxed, you should either use `text-shadow` or `filter: drop-shadow` instead of `box-shadow`